# If my master zone is not named "master" should my client zones.conf contain the zone "master"?

Tags: icinga2

My Icinga2 master zone (parent zone of all my other zones) is named "core" so I'm wondering whether the zones.conf files on my Icinga2 client machines should ever contain references to "master."

Here's an example of a client zone.conf file.

```
object Endpoint "mon-prod.polywog.net" {
        host = "191.120.289.30"
        port = "5665"
}

object Zone "master" {
        endpoints = [ "mon-prod.polywog.net" ]
}

object Zone "global-templates" {
  global = true
}

object Endpoint NodeName {
}

object Zone ZoneName {
        endpoints = [ NodeName ]
        parent = "master"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your root zone name is, use that instead of "master." The 'icinga2 node wizard' is not able to update config files very well. It does not reliably update constants.conf either.